# Nodejs watch mode

Tags: node.js

I want to use watch mode for node js
when I type : *node --watch index.js* I receive : **bad option: --watch**
is there any solution to that ?
PS : I'm using node.js version : 16.14.2

Comment: If you are using Code Runner extension, search for executor map in settings and add `--watch` in the json.

Answer (score 17):

This feature was only introduced on [v18.11](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v18.11.0/) and it's still experimental:

```
 nvm use v18.11.0   

 node --watch main.js
  (node:36224) ExperimentalWarning: Watch mode is an experimental feature. 
  This feature could change at any time
  (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) 
 
  hello 1
  hello 2
```

If you want to use the "watch mode" with Node.js on previous versions, you may want to have a look at:

- [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) for development
- [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for production

Answer (score 3):

You need to update to at least version 18 - https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v18.11.0/